# How to remove duplicate rows in postgresql?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I would like to remove duplicate entries in `Postgresql`.

There is no unique constraint, but I would like to consider all columns together to consider a row as a duplicate.

So we have a table containing following rows :

```
id   |   name   | age           | started_date  |Score |
-----|----------|---------------|---------------|------|
1    | tom      | 15            | 01/06/2022    |5     |
2    | tom      | 15            | 01/06/2022    |5     |
3    | henry    | 10            | 01/06/2022    |4     |
4    | john     | 11            | 01/06/2022    |6     |
...
```

I would like to consider all columns together to identify the duplicate rows.

How to achieve this in `Postgresql` ?

Comment: What have you tried? What's your schema? What's the sample data?

Comment: Did you try use DISTINCT on all your columns?

Comment: What do you mean by "remove"?  In a query or in the data itself?

Comment: related question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56695357/delete-duplicate-rows-postgresql

Answer (score 7):

PostgreSQL assigns a `ctid` pseudo-column to identify the physical location of each row. You could use that to identify different rows with the same values:

```
-- Create the table
CREATE TABLE my_table (num1 NUMERIC, num2 NUMERIC);

-- Create duplicate data
INSERT INTO my_table VALUES (1, 2);
INSERT INTO my_table VALUES (1, 2);

-- Remove duplicates
DELETE FROM my_table
WHERE ctid IN (SELECT ctid
               FROM   (SELECT ctid,
                              ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
                                PARTITION BY num1, num2) AS rn
                       FROM   my_table) t
               WHERE  rn > 1);
```

**[DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/fjVQuWYrRXYu5x7hG1TQ8L/0)**

Answer (score 0):

Let say your table has 2 columns, you can identify duplicates using. 
Post this :-

1) Insert this result into a temp table

2) Drop data from Main table

3) Insert data from temp table into main table

4) Drop temp table.

```
select col1, col2, count(*) as cnt
from table1
group by col1, col2
having  cnt > 1
```

Comment: Is there a way to delete found duplicate data directly from the table?

Comment: SQL mentioned in answer will do the same.